# PHP page structure SEO query

Tags: seo

I have what I presume is a simple question regarding PHP file structure.

If index.php has a doctype/meta/headers/body that are opened and closed within the script, but then contains header.php which again has a doctype/basic meta/headers/body that are opened and closed, and contains navigation.php that does the same and footer.php that does the same again.  What are the implications for SEO?

I'm a newbie, I'm sure it is very poor coding practice and crawlers will have issues indexing the page as it looks like there are 4 or 5 pages within one, but how fatal for SEO is it(if at all)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why in the world do you display several html documents on one page?

Comment: I wouldn't personally but been asked the question by a friend and didn't know the answer.

Comment: One page is one document. Several document on a page is wrong. A smart browser will try to correct it. But still... Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks, it struck me as very poor considering my friend paid (well) for the site.  I'll fix it for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you structure your site server-side doesn't matter, the final output you see in your browser's "view source" feature is all search engines can see. Use [W3's validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure everything is closed properly.

Edit: I think I misunderstood your question. No, you can't have more than one "document" per page.

Comment: The final output does have several sets of meta content (all be it empty), UTF etc where the internal php scritps (header/footer) are called down the page via firebug.  Will that have an effect?